# How to search for multiple values in a single field of mysql table using codeigniter active record?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, active-record-query

I have to search for multiple values in a field using mysql in codeigniter. Here follows my code.

**In Controller**

```
public function vpsearch()
{
  $data['info'] = $this->psearch_m->emp_search_form();

  $this->load->view("employer/result",$data);       

}
```

**IN Model**

```
public function emp_search_form()
{
  $skill = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('ps_skills'));
  $jrole = $this->input->post('ps_jobrole'));


  if ( $jrole !== NULL) 
  {
    return $this->db->get('js_edu_details');
    $this->db->like('js_skills','$skill');
  }
}
```

**In view** i.e, (../employer/result)

```
foreach($info->result() as $row)
{
  echo $row->js_id."<br/><br/>" ;
}
```

However I am getting all the records in 'js_edu_details' table instead of fields having searched 'skills'.

Where I am going wrong? Any help wud b appreciated, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
public function emp_search_form()
{
    $skill = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('ps_skills'));
    //$skill = $this->input->post('ps_skills', true);  other short way of getting the above result with `xss clean`
    if ( $jrole !== NULL) 
    {
        $this->db->like('js_skills',$skill); #remove the single quote around the `$skill`
        $res = $this->db->get('js_edu_details');
        echo $this->db->last_query(); #try to print the query generated
        return $res;
    }
}
```

`Return` statement should be after the `like` statement

Comment: Tried ur suggestions, no change. getting all records in table irrespective of value's in $skills.

Comment: What is `$jrole !== NULL`? where are you getting this from? Edited the code above try once again.

Comment: Thanx Nil'z , found the error!! I forgot to close the <?php form_close(); ?> in view. That is why unable to read the $skill value in  $this->db->like('js_skills',$skill); .. !! I found this only after printing the query ... Thank u so much for ur help.!!

Comment: Happie to help, consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should arrange the code properly like this

```
public function emp_search_form()
{
    $ps_skills  =   $this->input->post('ps_skills')
    $skill      = $this->security->xss_clean($ps_skills);

    if ( $jrole !== NULL) 
    {
        $this->db->like('js_skills','$skill');
        return $this->db->get('js_edu_details');
    }
}
```

Also you should note the condition will never meet. It will always give error `undefined variable $jrole`